# Atualizar a página(View) automaticamente no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, na minha aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, eu tenho uma tela de inscrição, onde o aluno clica no botão **"inscrição"** e se inscreve no curso, e o campo quantidade de vagas é decrementado. O problema é que minha `View` não atualiza após o aluno clicar no botão **"inscrição"**. Tenho que apertar o botão de atualizar do **browser** para que a `View` seja atualizada. Como eu faço para que essa `View` seja atualizada automaticamente após o clique no botão **"inscrição"**?.

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<h2>Catálago de Cursos</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@TempData["MensagemErro"]

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Ementa", "Curso")" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalaviso">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                        {
                       <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalAviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: {inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid")},
                    success: function() {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: você já debugou a sua função jquery? Parece que o document.ready não está atuando pela segunda vez. Debuga o que acontece quando você clica no botão e poste aqui para melhor ajudarmos. Eu falo isso, pois já tive problemas semelhantes com o document.ready e foi osso resolver.Não estou afirmando ser isso, por isso postar o resultado do debug é muito importante para o pessoal do site.

Answer (score 1):

olá,

Você pode retornar um Json informando a quantidade de vagas para a sua View. Segue exemplo :

http://www.guj.com.br/27920-como-obter-objeto-json-de-retorno-da-requisicao-ajax-jquery-aspnet-mvc-

HTML :

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>


<h2>Catálago de Cursos</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@TempData["MensagemErro"]

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Ementa", "Curso")" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalaviso">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas, new { id = "qtdVagas" + "@item.Id" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                        {
                       <input type="submit" value="Inscrição" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-success" data_toggle="modal" data_target="#modalAviso" data-inscricaoid="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {

                var id = $(this).data("inscricaoid");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: {inscricaoId: id},
                    success: function() {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        },
                    done: function(data){
                         $("#qtdVagas" + id).text(data.qtd)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Action MVC:

```
public ActionResult Inscricao(int id)
    {
        int quantidadeVagas;
        //Seu código
        ....        

        //Pega a quantidade de vagas
        quantidadeVagas = new SeuRepositorio().GetQuantidadeVagas(id)

        //Retorno
        return Json(quantidadeVagas);
    }
```

Comment: Você apenas vai ter que realizar um tratamento a mais no caso de não tiver mais vagas. @if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0). Basta você adicionar um "hide" nessa parte.

Comment: Já tenho um tratamento da quantidade de vagas @luã, só preciso que a pagina atualize automaticamente ao clicar no botão "inscrição".

Comment: A solução que te passei é para atualizar a quantidade de vagas, no caso basta a sua action retornar um json e no seu ajax atualizar a quantidade. Faltou algo ?

Comment: Não funcionou @Luã, ainda continuo tendo que apertar **F5** para atualizar a página.

Comment: Será que não ocorreu nenhum erro de java script ? Pois com essas alterações a quantidade de vagas tem que ser atualizadas no método done.

done: function(data){
                         $("#qtdVagas" + id).text(data.qtd)
                    }

Answer (score -3):

Uma solução é recarregar a página com JavaScript

```
document.location.reload(true);
```